# mapping ldap groups to local wso2 roles

Tags: oauth-2.0, ldap, wso2, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to map LDAP groups/roles to local roles in WSO2. I have created one service provider in WSO2 with OAuth/OpenID connect configurations. In Claim Configuration of the service provider, I have requested for roles by mapping OIDC groups claim URI to local role claim URI. I do the password grant using the username and password of a user from LDAP to get an access token. So when I hit the user info endpoint using access token. I should receive the local roles of WSO2 which are mapped with groups in LDAP as a part of user info.

Answer (score 3):

To map the ldap roles to WSO2 local roles, you have to do claim mapping. Please follow this document https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adding+Claim+Mapping for how to do claim mapping for a particular claim to an attribute in the userstore (LDAP).

When you are mapping the local role claim, please add the mapped attribute for Role claim in the userstore.

[image]

Please follow this document on how to configure claims for a service provider.: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider